# How to make work Remote desktop which is not working after activating?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

How to activate the remote desktop services after activating its stopped running  0 licence and befor activating it was running  i have attached screenshot for the reference
[remote desktop trouble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPi4P.jpg)
[remote desktop licence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzuCP.jpg)

does it automatically add the license of each user i had selected per user in group policy

Comment: The problem is stated in the screen shot. Per-device licensing is selected, and you don't have any licenses installed. You need to configure the host for per-user licensing, per the documentation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-license-session-hosts